# MS BotFramework V4 - Ignore User Input

Tags: node.js, botframework, chatbot, direct-line-botframework

Within Microsofts BotFramework V4, we would like find a way to ignore any user input while processing an async request, then resume the dialog state when the request is completed.

Are there any built in methods/functions to achieve this? And if not, are there any successful methods that have been used to accomplish this task? Google has been absolutely unhelpful but I feel this is an issue many face.

Language: NodeJS

Framework: Microsoft BotFramework v4

Comment: CancelAndHelpDialog class can be used to fulfill for your request.

Comment: You can also make use of inputHint property and set it to ignoringInput within the Activity. Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-add-input-hints?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#ignoring-input